# How would I output a json file in nodejs if a request with specific request headers are there?

Tags: node.js, json

I'm having a few issues with my code.

What I'm trying to do is make a json file that logs my iPhone battery percentage and all that.

But on request with the battery header, it will just output {} to a json.

This is the node code.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const request = require("request");
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

const fileName = "request_headers.json";

const saveHeadersToFile = async (headers, fileName) => {
  const jsonString = JSON.stringify({
    battery: headers["Battery"],
  });

  fs.writeFile(fileName, jsonString, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log("File written successfully");
    }
  });
};

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const headers = req.headers;

  if (!headers["thing"] || headers["thing"] !== "thing") {
    return;
  }

  await saveHeadersToFile(headers, fileName);

  res.send("Request received");
});

app.listen(3000);
```

This is the curl code to test.

`curl -H "thing: thing" -H "battery: 100" http://localhost:3000`

I expected it to output something like this.

```
{
   "info": {
        "battery": "[percentage]"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `Battery` lowercase in your node code.

```js
const jsonString = JSON.stringify({
    battery: headers["battery"],
  });
```